# What to display for differences of medians of discrete variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric

I am using the Mann-Withney U test to compare two samples of count data. In several situations, I find that there is a significant difference between the populations, but when I estimate the CI for the (pseudo)median using the wilcox.test in R, I get intervals like [-1e-5; -1e-6].

Now, I am confused about how to report these, and how to report them graphically: the CIs are so close to zero it becomes hard to say their do not include this value. Is it the case that the pseudomedian is not the statistic to report for differences of two samples of discrete variables? If so, are there alternatives?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data you are using?